# Invalid characters (??) inserted in the middle of email value

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

EF Core is saving wrong value for email column.

**For example:** the property class has a string value: `pna@pn.com.br`.

But when I check the stored value (either in SQL Server and getting the object with EF Core) is: `pna@pn.com??.br`.

The `??` doesn't exists in the original email value.

I have inserted directly in the database but this problem doesn't happen.

Steps to reproduce:

Try a simple insert with EF Core like implemented below:

The insert method from my repository class:

```
public void Insert(T entity)
{
       DbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
       DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

My mapped Entity class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using DataImoveis.Domain.Entities.Abstraction;

namespace DataImoveis.Domain.Entities
{
    [Table("SIL_IMOVEL_INQUILINO")]
    public class ImovelInquilino : BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("cod")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Cod { get; set; }

        [Column("propertyId")]
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }

        [Column("lastUpdatedDate")]
        public DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }

        [Column("tenantName")]
        public string TenantName { get; set; }

        [Column("tenantContact")]
        public string TenantContact { get; set; }

        [Column("tenantEmail")]
        public string TenantEmail { get; set; }

        [Column("tenantPhone")]
        public string TenantPhone { get; set; }

        [Column("tenantIndustry")]
        public string TenantIndustry { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My DbContext class:

```
using DataImoveis.Domain.Entities;
using DataImoveis.Domain.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace DataImoveis.Infrastructure
{
    public class DbContext : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<ImovelInquilino> ImovelInquilino { get; set; }

        private IOptions<Settings> settings;

        public override DatabaseFacade Database { get { return base.Database; } }

        public DbContext(IOptions<Settings> settings) : base() =>
            this.settings = settings;

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                settings.Value.ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection
            );
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) { }

    }
}
```

The column details in the database:

```
[tenantEmail] [varchar](70) NULL,
```

There's no trigger or later updates for this field.

I enabled logging for `DbContext` operations to check the parameter sent to database from EF Core, and I think that everything is ok:

```
Executed DbCommand (24ms) [Parameters=[(...) @p14='pna@pn.com​​.br.' (...)]
```

Further technical details

- EF Core version: 3.1.4
- Database provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.1.3
- Database: SQL Server 2019
- Target framework: .NET Core 3.1
- Operating system: Both on Ubuntu 18.04 (In WSL2) or Windows 10
- IDE: VSCode

Comment: varchar is ascii, nvarchar is unicode

Comment: I just copy-paste this text to interactive C# window to see the length: `"pna@pn.com​​.br.".Length`. Result is `16`. There IS two invisible characters right after `.com`.

Comment: Thanks for help me! The problem was like you said. I even noted that because a was so absorbed with SQL Server and EFCore. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your email address has got two Unicode characters 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (E2 80 8B) between 'com' and '.br.' (I copied text from your log into text file, save it and had a look at hex representation:

[image]

Since DB column is varchar, these unicode characters cannot be saved in DB as is and DB converted them to placeholder '?'.

Either define DB column as nvarchar (and all Unicode characters will be stored as is), or remove such characters from input data.

Comment: Thank you for help me and to be so quick in your response. I was so absorbed in SQL Server and Entity Framework issues that I even noted this little detail.
I escaped the content string with regex:
content = Regex.Replace(content, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]+", string.Empty);